# Get Physical Location of Types of an Assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, assemblies

May seem to be a similar question to [GetReferencedAssembly locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582510/get-pathes-of-assemblies-used-in-type), but my question is getting physical locations of the types in those referencedAssemblies.
Can I get information from pdb? Or can I use cecil?

Ultimately my goal is search for a keyword for a specified assembly, and list all the files [.cs/ .fs/ .vb] that uses this keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/getting_file_and_line_numbers_without_deploying_the_pdb_file.htm) is a interesting blog how to extract that information as xml from pdb files

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PDB Parser for that. I know that [.NET Massdownloader](http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12318) has a set of classes that do that under DownloadLibrary.Classes.PdbParsing.