# Get the paths of all referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I get the paths of all the assemblies referenced by the currently executing assembly? `GetReferencedAssmblies()` gives me the `AssemblyName[]`s. How do I get to where they are loaded from, from there?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582510/get-pathes-of-assemblies-used-in-type

Comment: For a fully working example of how to get all referenced assemblies, recursively, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies/26300241#26300241.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot know until the assembly is loaded.  The assembly resolution algorithm is complicated and you can't reliably guess up front what it will do.  Calling the `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)` override will get you a reference to the assembly, and its Location property tells you what you need.

However, you *really* don't want to load assemblies up front, *before* the JIT compiler does it.  It is inefficient and the likelihood of problems is not zero.  You could for example fire an `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event before the program is ready to respond to it.  Avoid asking this question.

Answer (score 5):

Following Hans Passant's answer, and since the `CodeBase` property always contained `null`, I came up with this. It might not find all assemblies since they might not all be already loaded. In my situation, I had to find all reference of a previously loaded assembly, so it worked well:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAssemblyFiles(Assembly assembly)
{
    var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    return assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(name => loadedAssemblies.SingleOrDefault(a => a.FullName == name.FullName)?.Location)
        .Where(l => l != null);
}
```

Usage:

```
var assemblyFiles = GetAssemblyFiles(typeof(MyClass).Assembly);
```

Comment: It would be good idea to avoid returning null values when assembly is not loaded (just continue the loop instead).

Comment: Good idea @SlobodanSavkovic, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `CodeBase` property should provide the full path name.

Comment: Unfortunately, CodeBase returns null on every referenced assembly. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the URL location of the assembly like this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()[0].CodeBase
```

Comment: CodeBase returns null. The solution is in the post that JasonEvans linked to in his comment to the original post. Also, Hans Passant has the right answer, too.