# How to get the physical path of the referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have one main assembly, this assembly has referenced some more assembly. I am able to get those referenced assmbly names. But, i am unable to retrive the physical path of those referenced assemblies. Any one can help me on this?

I am using the following code.

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(txtFileName.Text);
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

    foreach (AssemblyName an in a.GetReferencedAssemblies())  {
    Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(an);                
    MessageBox.Show(an.FullName.ToString() + "Location : " + asm.CodeBase.ToString());
    }
```

It gives me the path of the system assembly "mscorlib". But when it try to retrive the user created assembly, it says "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193516/get-the-paths-of-all-referenced-assemblies - OR - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582510/get-pathes-of-assemblies-used-in-type

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps like this:

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(asm)).Location;

string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName( path);
```

Comment: You need to put a class there that is contained in the assembly of which you want the path.

Comment: i am getting the error at Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(an);  in my code. It says not able to get the path.

Comment: Lets assume, that in the assembly is a class named "FooBar" than you would adjust my code to : string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(FooBar)).Location;