# How to get the full path of a referenced dll in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with a rather large code base and I have a project that I have added a reference to a dll. However, when I make changes to the referenced dll, I do not see my changes. I suspect that it is grabbing an older version from who knows where. Is there a way to use Path.GetFullPath() or something where I can put the instance of the object into and get a string with the full path of the dll where the object came from?

```
 var FromDll = new DllClass();
 string result = FromDll.GetResult(); //No changes are seen here
 //What can I do to find out the full Path of where FromDll is coming from?
```

Comment: you want to get the referenced assembly path?

Comment: Check this solution: [Get paths of assemblies used in Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582510/get-paths-of-assemblies-used-in-type)

Comment: AppDomain has methods for pulling running assemblies and examining them at runtime.

Comment: Fusion log can show you how assemblies are loaded, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer so you don't need any hack like that.

Comment: `FromDll.GetType().Assembly.Location` will give you that.

Comment: Yes thank you! It needed just a little bit of work but that solution got me going on the right path to get the answer! And it was referencing it in a completely unexpected location.